# How compress an image with TIFF format in OpenCV c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I proceed some filtering on an Image then I want to save it through imwrite command with TIFF format but the size is big. As in JPEG format can compress a image to lower size. How do I do it in TIFF format. (I'm using OpenCV C++).

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42ac) seems to imply that `imwrite()` can't create a compressed tiff, as there's no relevant option.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a trick or something like that. :)

Comment: Use some external image manipulation program like GraphicsMagick to compress the image after creating it? (`gm convert -compress LZW orig.tiff smaller.tiff` should do it for that example; other tools are obviously different)

Comment: @Shawn, Is GraphicsMagick free license for commercial purpose?

Comment: I think it's BSD. The website will tell you.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from v3.4.6, `cv::ImwriteFlags` includes `IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION` (see https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html).

In `opencv-python==4.5.5.62`, I have successfully used

```py
import cv2
cv2.imwrite(filename, array, params=(cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 1))      # None
cv2.imwrite(filename, array, params=(cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 5))      # LZW
cv2.imwrite(filename, array, params=(cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 8))      # Adobe Deflate
cv2.imwrite(filename, array, params=(cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 32946))  # Deflate
```

See also https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/compression.html